# Reactive Java: Insert item in stream based on comparison of two items

Tags: java, reactive-programming

I want to insert item in a stream if a condition is met by comparing two items in the stream. Stream means `Observable<Object>`

In diagram it will look like

```
10 -> 20 -> 40 -> 50 -> 70 -> 90 (input stream)
|if two items are more than 10 apart, insert item that is 10 times the previous item in comparison, both comparison items are always emitted|
10 -> 20 -> 200 -> 40 -> 50 -> 500 -> 70 -> 700 -> 90 (output stream)
```

Above is just an example. In reality, I want to have a generic insertion item that is mapped from previous item.

Thanks.

Comment: Please show us what you've tried. We are here to solve problems, not doing your work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The usual way to do that in Rx is by using flatMap/[concatMap](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#concatMap(rx.functions.Func1)) and composing observables. In your case you also need to use [scan](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#scan(rx.functions.Func2)) or zipWith to get access to both the current and the previous element (you could use a state as well but that's not Rx-y):

```
sourceObs.startWith(0).zip(sourceObs, (prev, next) ->
    next > prev+10 ?
        Observable.just(prev*10, next) :
        Observable.just(next))
    .concatMap(o -> o);
```

Comment: Brilliant solution. Thank you!